# creating hollow square c++

Tags: c++

I have written this code but somehow when it asks the user to enter a new number to create a square, it doesn't print the square. Could anyone anyone explain / help me please?

```
// ask user to repeat the process again at end of the first promt

while ( num > 1 || num < 20 )
    {
  ask user to repeat the process again at end of the first promt
    while ( num > 1 || num < 20 )
    {
        // ask user t enter a square
        cout << "Please enter size of square between #1-20: \n";
        cin >> buf; num = atoi (buf.c_str());
        cin.ignore(1000, 10);


        // process of printing square
        while ( num >= a)
        {
            b = 1;
            while ( num >= b )
            {
                if ( a == 1 || a == num || b == 1 || b == num )
                    cout << "*";
                else
                    cout << " ";
                b++;
            }
            cout << endl;
            a++;
        }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. And I seem to notice some of the comments in your code aren't actually `//comments`

Comment: Guess you are doing homework? Consider that the left and right hand sides are always the same i.e. "*" for the left and "*\n" for the right. You just need to fill in the middle with the right character and do that for the right number of lines

Comment: `( num > 1 || num < 20 )` is always true. I suspect you want `&&`

Comment: This code is a weird mix of C and C++. Why read data into a `char` buffer and then call `atoi` on it?

Answer (score 2):

I see no code where you initialise `a` to 1 so it may be it has some arbitrary value. If that arbitrary value is greater than `num`, the outer loop will never start.

For what it's worth, I would be using `for` loops in this case since you know in advance what the limits are, something like the following pseudo-code:

```
# Top line
for i = 1 to num (inclusive):
    output "*"
output newline

# Middle lines
for i = 2 to num-1:
    output "*"               # Left char
    for j = 2 to num-1:      # Middle chars
        output " "
    output "*" and newline   # Right char

# Bottom line
for i = 1 to num (inclusive):
    output "*"
output newline
```

Then you don't have to worry about condition checking within the loop body.

A good rule of thumb is to use `for` for a known-before-the-start count of iterations, `while` for a loop where you don't know in advance how often you'll iterate.

Another likely problem is your condition:

```
while ( num > 1 || num < 20 )
```

Regardless of the value of `num`, that is always true, since you're using logical-or `||`. Think of the possibilities:

```
num <= 1     : false or true  -> true
num == 2..19 : true  or true  -> true
num >= 20    : true  or false -> true
```

If you want to continue looping while you have a value *outside* of the range 1..20, you should use:

```
while ( num < 1 || num > 20 )
```

and you then end up with the following:

```
num <  1     : true  or false -> true
num == 1..20 : false or false -> false
num >  20    : false or true  -> true
```

---

There are quite a few other potential problems with your code, to wit:

- You appear to have the outer loop in there twice.
- You don't appear to define `b` or `num`.
- You don't appear to set `num` before the outer loop (which checks it).
- I suspect you meant to close the `while ( num > 1 || num < 20 )` loop immediately after the `cin.ignore()` call since it's meant to keep going until you get a value from 1 to 20 and *then* draw the square. As it stands, a square will be drawn even if you enter 99.

Comment: I define a at the beginning of the program.  int a; a=1

Comment: @Oruz, ideally that should have been mentioned in the original question. However, there are plenty of other things in the answer that you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best code - but it can be done in six lines. Here goes.

```
   for (int y = o; y < height; ++ y) {
       for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
          cout << (y == 0 || y == (height - 1) || x == 0 || x == (width - 1) ? '*' : ' ' );
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
```